# Error in NETWORKIT: MissingDependencyError: Optional dependency tabulate is not installed

Tags: python, networkit

I keep getting the error below when I try to detect communities with:

```
nk.community.detectCommunities(G_kit)
```

```
PLM(balanced,pc,turbo) detected communities in 0.26202988624572754 [s]
solution properties:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MissingDependencyError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-153-c567dea502f3> in <module>
----> 1 nk.community.detectCommunities(G_kit)

networkit/community.pyx in networkit.community.detectCommunities()

networkit/community.pyx in networkit.community.inspectCommunities()

MissingDependencyError: Optional dependency tabulate is not installed
```

Is there anything I can install to avoid that?
Many thanks!

Comment: It looks like you don't have `tabulate` installed. Try to install it via pip, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's solved my problem!